# Get application's root url with Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I'm using an Akka Scheduler to make a request to the root url of my Play Framework application every minute to refresh the application's cache if it expires.

At the moment I am calling `WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:9000/").get();` as I am working on my localhost. Obviously, when I push to production I will change this to request the production URL.

Is there a function to obtain the root url automatically, so that I don't have to change this each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 solutions, get it from reverse route OR from config OR from both (with config priority):

```java
String reverseRoute = routes.Application.index().absoluteURL(request());

String refreshUrlFromConf = Play.application().configuration().getString("refreshUrl");

String mixed = Play.application().configuration().getString(
        "refreshUrl",
        routes.Application.index().absoluteURL(request())
);
```

If you want to use config approach, of course you need to add this to your `application.conf`:

```
refreshUrl = "http://your-instance.tld"
```

BTW you don't need to refresh cache yourself, it will be refreshed at the very first request, right after cache termination.